# Get attributes from a returned XML string

Tags: php, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

I am trying to take an XML string returned from a call to CEBroker WebServices such as:

```
<licensees>
    <licensee valid="true" State="FL" licensee_profession="RN" 
        licensee_number="2676612" state_license_format="" first_name="HENRY" last_name="GEITER" ErrorCode="" Message="" TimeStamp="2/18/2022 6:43:20 PM" />
</licensees>
```

And parse the string to obtain the values of the attributes as they will always be the same, and there will be only one licensee per string. The XML string is returned in $xmlresponse, and when I print it out using print_r it is correct, but when I try to parse, I always get nothing.

I tried

```
$xml_string = simplexml_load_string($xmlresponse);
print_r ("this is my xml after going through simplexml_load_string" . $xml_string);
```

//The above line prints nothing for $xml_string;

```
$json = json_encode($xml_string);
            print_r($json);
            $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
            echo "<p>Array contents are as follows</p>";
            print_r($array);
            var_dump ($array);
            echo "<p>Array contents ended!</p>";
```

I am new to XML and just need to know how to parse nodes and, in this case attributes, for returned XML data or XML files.

Thanks

Comment: This is the XML data returned from the webservices call: <licensees><licensee valid="true" State="FL" licensee_profession="RN" licensee_number="2676612" state_license_format="" first_name="HENRY" last_name="GEITER" ErrorCode="" Message="" TimeStamp="2/18/2022 5:57:03 PM" /></licensees>

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71181151/edit) your question to include all relevant info instead of adding it as comments. That will make sure everyone reading the question will see it. It's also hard to read code in comments.

Comment: tried and failed, so that is why I added the data in a comment.  I can close this question and spend more time and energy trying to put all the info in one box instead of two if no one can help me in a  reasonable amount of time.

Comment: You need to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) XML as code, or it will ignore the tags. I fixed it for you though.

Comment: rtm: https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: tried the link method and nothing

Comment: Here is the code:  echo "this is my xml returned from webservice:" . $xmlresponse . "!!!<p></p>";
   $xml_string = simplexml_load_string($xmlresponse);
   //This loop displays absolutely nothing
   echo "starting attribute loop. <br />";

   foreach ($xml_string->licensee[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
                echo $a , '=' , $b;
            }
            echo "finished attribute loop.";

Comment: Here is the output, note something in the foreach loop must break as the echo after it does not execute.           this is my xml returned from webservice: <licensees><licensee valid="true" State="FL" licensee_profession="RN" licensee_number="2676612" state_license_format="" first_name="HENRY" last_name="GEITER" ErrorCode="" Message="" TimeStamp="2/18/2022 9:49:43 PM" /></licensees>!!!

starting attribute loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, try the following, which assumes a response with two licensees:

```
$xmlresponse = '
<licensees>
   <licensee valid="true" State="FL" licensee_profession="RN" licensee_number="2676612" state_license_format="" first_name="HENRY" last_name="GEITER" ErrorCode="" Message="" TimeStamp="2/18/2022 6:43:20 PM" />
   <licensee valid="false" State="NY" licensee_profession="DC" licensee_number="1234" state_license_format="" first_name="JOHN" last_name="DOE" ErrorCode="" Message="" TimeStamp="1/1/2023 6:43:20 PM" />
</licensees>
';
$xml_string = simplexml_load_string($xmlresponse);
$licensees = $xml_string->xpath("//licensee");

foreach ($licensees as $licensee) {
    foreach ($licensee ->xpath('./@*') as $attribute){
    echo $attribute." ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
true FL RN 2676612  HENRY GEITER   2/18/2022 6:43:20 PM 
false NY DC 1234  JOHN DOE   1/1/2023 6:43:20 PM
```

Output

Comment: Actually I will upvote this as it worked, but it inadvertently also revealed the other code worked. The problem seems  to be that what the webservices is returning in xmlresponse is ACTUALLY <string xmlns="http://www.cebroker.com/CEBrokerWebService/">&lt;licensees&gt;&lt;licensee valid="true" State="FL" licensee_profession="RN" licensee_number="2676612" state_license_format="" first_name="HENRY" last_name="GEITER" ErrorCode="" Message="" TimeStamp="2/19/2022 3:06:51 AM" /&gt;&lt;/licensees&gt;</string>

Comment: and the substitution of &gt; and &lt; for > and < is making it not behave as XML. But, when I added your code which had xmlresponse assigned with > and < the xmlresponse->licensee[0]->attributes code in the foreach loop worked too. Is there a way to convert what I am getting back from webservices into proper XML?

Comment: @HenryGeiter There's probably a way (or more to do that), but you should probably pose it as a separate question - others may have the same issue.

Comment: I did as "convert string to xml in PHP"